# Using a select form field for the field that selects the groups where a node is posted 

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

The form for creating a node for the content type that has been set as content type for the Organic Groups module has checkboxes for choosing the groups where a node is posted; I want to use a select form field instead of the checkboxes.

How should I alter the form field?

I have tried some patches from drupal.org, but they do not works correctly.

I have used the following code.

```
/**
 * Helper function; Make the groups audience accept only a single group.
 */
function og_single_group_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (module_exists('og_access')) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'og_single_group');
    drupal_add_js($path . '/og_single_group_hideoption.js');
  }

  if (!empty($form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']) && ($form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#type'] != 'value')) {
    $options = array();
    $options = array(t('Personal blog')) + $form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#options'];
    $form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#multiple'] = FALSE;
    $form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#options'] = $options;
    // Add own submit handler so we can cast the groups back to an array.
    $form['#submit'][] = 'og_single_group_submit';
  }
}

 /**
  * Submit handler; Since we permit only a single group per content, we need to
  * case to groups into an array
  */
function og_single_group_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   if (!empty($form_state['values']['og_groups']) && !is_array($form_state['values']['og_groups'])) {
     $form_state['values']['og_groups'] = drupal_map_assoc((array)$form_state['values']['og_groups']);
   } 
  else if (empty($form_state['values']['og_groups'])) {
    $form_state['values']['og_groups'] = array();
  }
}
```

The code causes the following error:

> Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in /var/www/mysite/sites/all/modules/contrib/og/og.module on line 1303.

Answer (score 2):

I am replying basing on what you wrote in the comment to your question.

Organic Groups shows checkboxes or a select field basing on the number of groups that are listed in the "Audience" form field. If the number of groups is less than 20, the module will use checkboxes; otherwise, it will use a select box.

There is no way to change which form field is used, except using a module that alters the form fields added by Organic Groups. The following code, contained in og.module, is the code that adds the audience form field to the node edit form.

```
// show multi-select. if less than 20 choices, use checkboxes.
$type = $cnt >= 20 || $is_optgroup ? 'select' : 'checkboxes';
$max_groups = variable_get('og_max_groups_'.$node->type,'');
$description_max_groups = ($max_groups && !user_access('administer nodes')) ? format_plural($max_groups," Limited to !max_groups choice."," Limited to !max_groups choices.", array('!max_groups' => $max_groups)):'';
$form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups'] = array(
  '#type' => $type,
  '#title' => t('Audience'),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'og-audience'),
  '#options' => $type == 'checkboxes' ? array_map('filter_xss', $options) : $options,
  '#required' => $required,
  '#description' =>  format_plural(count($options), 'Show this post in this group.', 'Show this post in these groups.') . $description_max_groups,
  '#default_value' => $groups ? $groups : array(),
  '#required' => $required,
  '#multiple' => TRUE);
```

It is enough to have a module that executes the following line, and the form field will always use a select box to show the list of groups to which associate a post.

```
$form['og_nodeapi']['visible']['og_groups']['#type'] = 'select';
```

The code needs to be executed inside the implementation of `hook_form_alter()`, or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces) module there is the Spaces OG module.  This removes the "audience" field, and makes it appear where you can only post to a single group.